# How to add new column based on other columns

Tags: r

My data contains `0` and `1` values in two vectors:

- `bad = c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1)`
- `good = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0)`

I want to create new column based on these two columns. If `bad` and `good` are equal to `0`(or `1`) then observation in new column must be `0`(or `1`) or if `bad` is `1` `good` is `0` then new observation in new column should be `1` and vice versa.

Comment: Can you show what your expected output look like? Also read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: there are 4 possible combinations, it would be good to see the desired outcome for each, `vice versa` is not clear

Comment: A wild guess you might need something like `df$new <- ifelse(df$bad==df$good, df$good, df$bad)`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are asking for one of the logical operators.

**OR**

```r
as.integer(bad | good)
```

**AND**

```r
as.integer(bad & good)
```

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html for more.